# Load popup on hover data from json file for datamaps

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, datamaps

The datamaps "[Getting started](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)" page has a section on customizing the text when a user hovers over a specific country. However, they do so by hard-coding that info:

```
<script>
    var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            HIGH: '#afafaf',
            LOW: '#123456',
            MEDIUM: 'blue',
            UNKNOWN: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            defaultFill: 'green'
        },
        data: {
            IRL: {
                fillKey: 'LOW',
                numberOfThings: 2002
            },
            USA: {
                fillKey: 'MEDIUM',
                numberOfThings: 10381
            }
        },
        geographyConfig: {
            popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
                return ['<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>',
                        'Number of things in ' + geo.properties.name,
                        ': ' + data.numberOfThings,
                        '</strong></div>'].join('');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I would like to load that info from an external .json file so that I can update it easily. How can I do this? I've tried setting `dataURL`, but that expects a complete topojson file, which I don't need to update.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataUrl` at the root level can take a json or csv file, like this example here: http://bl.ocks.org/markmarkoh/11331459

```
      var election = new Datamap({
        scope: 'usa',
        element: document.getElementById('container1'),
        geographyConfig: {
          popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
            return data && data.info && "<div class='hoverinfo'><strong>" + data.info + "</strong></div>";
          },
          highlightOnHover: false,
          borderColor: '#444',
          borderWidth: 0.5
        },
        dataUrl: 'data.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        fills: {
          'Visited': '#306596',
          'neato': '#0fa0fa',
          'Trouble': '#bada55',
          defaultFill: '#dddddd'
        }
      });
```

While the resource at `data.json` looks like:

```
{
  "NY": {"fillKey": "Visited", "anotherProperty": "Born here"},
  "TX": {"fillKey": "Visited", "anotherProperty": "Live here"},
  "CA": {"fillKey": "Visited", "anotherProperty": "Here while writing this code"}
}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work with json for me, even if copying your code, but the example behind the link works beautifully with .csv.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Same for me. Json doesn't work but CSV works like a charm